# Why my code is not working and and also not showing any error in react-native

Tags: react-native

My code is not running and also not showing any errors. I tried it many times in react-native, so please help to figure out my code, so I am also sharing my github code, so you can pull it and run  it (only header is coming, image  and text is not coming). I am sharing my github link here:
https://github.com/Ranipandit/smart-closet-react-native

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately the community here will find it difficult to help you unless you copy and paste your actual code into the question (use the {} button to label it as code). (Links may not remain valid for ever, and StackOverflow is a Q&A knowledge base; also, busy community members will find it easier to see the code in front of them on the question.)

Answer (score 0):

I checked your Github Repo.

The problem with your code is the background image was not in an absolute position and the text was white with a white background (it was there but it was not visible).

A better solution is to remove your Backgroundimage component and use the one by ReactNative (BackgrpoundImage) to create a component with image as background:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images#background-image-via-nesting

Your code Home component should look something similar to this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  ImageBackground,
} from 'react-native';
import {Header} from 'react-native-elements';

export default class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <View>
          <Header
              placement="left"
              leftComponent={{icon: 'menu', color: '#fff'}}
              centerComponent={{text: 'SMART CLOSET', style: {color: '#fff', fontWeight: "bold"}}}
              rightComponent={{icon: 'home', color: '#fff'}}
          />
          <ImageBackground 
              source={require('./images/clothes.gif')} 
              style={styles.imageBackground}
          >
            <Text style={styles.text}>
              Welcome to Smart Closet
            </Text>
          </ImageBackground>
        </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  imageBackground: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
  },
  text: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: 'white',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    fontSize: 32
  }
});
```